# Perform Lstrip on values of a dictionary when each value is a list

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, list-comprehension, strip

Hello I am trying to figure out how to perform an lstrip on each value of a dictionary when the value is a list. Lets call the name of the dictionary **test**.

This is an example of one key-value pair in the dictionary test. There are 100+ key-value pairs.

```
  'names: ['10jack',
  '300alex',
  '200michael',
  '105mike',
  '234joe',
  '50robert']'
```

I tried the following and it wasn't working since the value of the dictionary was a list. I am trying to remove the numbers in front of each name.

`clean_dict = {key: item.lstrip('0123456789.- ') for key, item in test.items()}`

Comment: What are you trying to strip?

Comment: By default, `.strip()` only removes whitespace.  If you want it to remove digits, use `.strip('0123456789')`

Comment: I'm trying to use an lstrip(('0123456789.- ')) I forgot to mention that piece of code let me update it.

Comment: In this code, `item` is a list, which doesn't have a `.strip()` method.  I don't see how this code even runs.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension to iterate over all the list elements.

```
clean_dict = {key.strip(): [el.lstrip('0123456789.- ') for el in value] for key, value in test.items()}
```